# Filterable collection mvvm

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, collections

Does it any good implementation of Filterable Collection for C#?

What is required:

```
var data = GetEmployees();

_filtered = new FilterableCollection<Employee>(data);
_filtered.SetFilterExpression(empl => empl.DepartmentId == SelectedDepartment.Id);

...

set
{
  SelectedDepartment = value;
  _filtered.UpdateRepresentation();
}
```

Paging, CustomFilterBuilder and Virtualization would be a plus but not required at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this... WPF already does supports this, via the [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) interface.

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data);
view.Filter = o => ((Employee)o).DepartmentId == SelectedDepartment.Id;
```